# Powershell test-path issues

Tags: powershell, script, code

I am trying to use test-path to find if a path or path/file is valid.

For example I can do:

```
test-path -literalpath "c:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv"
```

This returns true when it is and false when its not.

Now, here is my problem and where I have no idea at all in terms of looping. Ideally what I want Powershell to do is read the file "Study Setup.csv" which contains a column called PATH and check if the filepaths in each record for this column are valid.

If not then output the paths that are not valid.

I have very limited experience in Powershell other than one liners so looping is alien as are many things.

I know this is not a code writing service but any help he much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't even need any loops, you simply need [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7)

```
Import-CSV "C:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv" | Where-Object { !(Test-Path $_.Path) }
```

This would already only return the objects where `Test-Path` returns `$false`

For export I'd go for this, because I would want all my CSV Properties, not just the path:

```
Import-CSV "C:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv" | Where-Object { !(Test-Path $_.Path) } | Export-CSV "C:\MyFolder\False Paths in Study Setup.csv"
```

But if you really only want the path you can do this:

```
Import-CSV "C:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv" | Where-Object { !(Test-Path $_.Path) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | Out-File "C:\MyFolder\False Paths in Study Setup.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks....this looks like a nice simple solution....however I am getting the following errors

Comment: I get the below:

Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:145
+ ... oad\Study Setup.csv" | Where-Object { !(Test-Path $_.Sap_Path) } | Ex ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Comment: Actually it does appear to work, I think the errors in the terminal window are just about missing paths in the column ? is there any way to not output warnings/errors if there is no path ?

Comment: @Colm yes, you can just change `!(Test-Path $_.Path)` to `!(Test-Path $_.Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)` or the shorter `!(Test-Path $_.Path -ea 0)`

Comment: Fantastic....this worked....many thanks for your help on this and also to all who also provided help

Comment: Sorry to bother especially as I closed this....but when it find no issues and produces an empty CSV file it put the following text in the first cell:

ÿþ

This is an odd UTF-161e format, is there a way to stop this, I still want the empty file but just totally empty ?

Comment: Seems -Encoding ASCII added to the output resolves this...marking complete :-)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but feeling cocky :D

```
$Source   = 'c:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv'
$BadPaths = 'c:\MyFolder\BadPths.txt'

If ( test-path -literalpath $Source ) {
   ( Import-Csv $Source ).Path | ForEach{
      If ( -not ( test-path -literalpath $_ )) {
         '"{0}"' -f $_
      }
   }
} | Add-content $BadPaths
```

I like SImonS's reminder about `Wheere-Object`. I'd incorporate it this way (and assuming we can trust that `$Source` file exists):

```
Filter Quote-String { '"{0}"' -f $_ }
$Source   = 'c:\MyFolder\Study Setup.csv'
$BadPaths = 'c:\MyFolder\BadPths.txt'

( Import-Csv $Source ).Path | Where{
    -not ( Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ )
} | Quote-String | Add-Content $BadPaths
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to loop in PowerShell, [see the help files on the topic](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20about_loop&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershelabout_loop&sc=1-19&sk=&cvid=C6AFE4D94AC3469BB5F3234C1C4EA738).
Try this...

```
Import-Csv -Path "$PWD\Study Setup.csv" | 
ForEach-Object {
    If (-Not (Test-Path -Path $PSItem.Path))
    {$PSItem.Path | Out-File -FilePath "$PWD\BadPaths.csv" -Append -WhatIf}
    Else {"The path $($PSItem.Path) already exists"}
}
# Results
<#
The path D:\Temp already exists
What if: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target "D:\Scripts\BadPaths.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target "D:\Scripts\BadPaths.csv".
#>
```

If all looks good then remove the -WhatIf for a complete run.

FYI, of course, PowerShell offers many ways to do X or Y. Here is a different kind of approach to determine the existence of a folder, files, etc. It's all a matter of choice, code style, etc.

[Using Assertions](https://powershell.one/code/10.html)